# How to trigger a jenkins job whenever some changes are pushed to gerrit server

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I have to trigger a jenkins job whenever a new patchset is created, that is whenever some changes are pushed to a specific project and specific branch in gerrit server it should trigger that jenkins job.

I have installed the Gerrit plugin in jenkins, gerrit version is 2.16.5.

It seems some configuration is needed to be done but I do not know as I am new to Jenkins and Gerrit.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the gerrit-trigger instructions? What have you done so far? What issues have you found?

Comment: I have a doubt in that, it seems a ssh keyfile should be created in the gerrit server settings, by default it has shown a ssh keyfile as "/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa" and I am not sure what it is. 

If I click on "Test Connection" button it shows "Connection error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail" error

Comment: First you need to configure the ssh key of the user which Jenkins will use to access Gerrit. First Log in Gerrit and go to Settings > SSH Keys to add the PUBLIC key, then tell Jenkins where it can find the corresponding PRIVATE key (at /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa or in any other location).